# Yii url routing

Tags: yii, routes

i have a url example.com/information/london. whenver some one calls this url i want to call a controller information and its index method. but i want to pass slug as jobs-in-london i.e. example.com/information/jobs-in-london how can i achive this by writing url rule in config/main.php.
i.e i want to redirect my page example.com/information/london to example.com/information/jobs-in-london but dont want to use .htaccess i want to achieve this only by url routing rules i have tried this by writing

```
'<_c:(information)>/<slug:london>'=>'information/index/jobs-in-london'
```

but this wont work for me.

```
class InformationController extends Controller
{


    public function actionIndex($slug)
    {

        CVarDumper::dump($slug,10,true);
        exit;

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. You may mean either of the following:

---

Url:

```
example.com/information/london
example.com/information/singapore
```

Rule:

```
'information/<slug>' => 'information/index',
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex($slug)
{
    $slug = "jobs-in-".$slug;

    var_dump($slug);
}
```

Slug Result:

```
jobs-in-london
jobs-in-singapore
```

---

Url:

```
example.com/information/jobs-in-london
example.com/information/jobs-in-singapore
```

Rule:

```
'information/<slug:jobs-in-.+>' => 'information/index',
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex($slug)
{
    var_dump($slug);
}
```

Slug Result:

```
jobs-in-london
jobs-in-singapore
```

Comment: thank you samuel for your answer....
actualy i want to route my only one request 
if i hit this url example/information/lodon
i want the slug should be passed as jobs-in-london in other words
i want to add this rule in my config
information/london => information/index/jobs-in-london
hope you got it what i am trying to say

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you will exactly have to do in the routes:

```
'<controller:(information)>/<slug:>' => '<controller>/index'
```

and here is how to add the slug while you're creating the URL:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('information/index', array('slug' => 'jobs-in-london'));
```

and to check what the slug is, what you did to the function is correct.